# How to reinstall apk if it is present?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, reinstall, virtual-device-manager

This happened when i try to use my Redmi note 4 as a virtual Device.
and the message clearly say that to reinstall the apk but my question is how and where ?
As I am a beginner I don't know the process.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGcdC.png)

Comment: This typically happens, when there is already an app installed with the same package id but a different signature key.

Comment: so how could i get rid of that ?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using `adb` yourself via terminal instead of Android Studio executing the `adb` commands on your behalf.

`adb install -r location/of/<application>.apk` will overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I solved it, as I am a Redmi note 4 user I need to turn off miui optimisation(in developers option) and reboot the mobile.